# Overriding equals() method in a generic class

Tags: java, generics

I want to override equals() method in this class. I follow the usual rules while overriding the equals() method but and I typecast the Object into my class type

but in my equals() method, I want to return true only if the objects are of the same generic type.

How can I check the run time type of the instance in my equals() method?

Here is my code:

```
public class GenericsRunTimeType<T> {

private T foo;
public GenericsRunTimeType(T foo){
    this.foo = foo;

}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;

    // Before doing this I want to test if obj and this are of the same generic type
    GenericsRunTimeType other = (GenericsRunTimeType) obj;
    if(other.equals(obj))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Is it not giving the desired result?    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())

Answer (score 7):

In your case you can just check:

`foo.getClass().equals(other.foo.getClass())`

This is because you already have a member of class `T` in your class. However in common case when you do not have such member take a look on answer done by @Rohit Jain. (+1)

Comment: However, just because `foo.getClass().equals(other.foo.getClass())` does not mean the type parameters are the same. Conversely, the type parameters could be the same and `foo.getClass().equals(other.foo.getClass())` may not be true.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use *Reflection*, but I would consider it as my last resort.

Another option, which I would prefer here, is to pass `Class<T>` parameter in constructor, and store it in a field:

```
private T foo;
private Class<T> clazz;
public GenericsRunTimeType(T foo, Class<T> clazz){
    this.foo = foo;
    this.clazz = clazz;
}
```

And then in `equals` method, do the comparison like so:

```
if (this.clazz == ((GenericsRunTimeType)obj).clazz) {
    System.out.println("Same type");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am giving another direction: Do you really need to check the equality of the TYPE PARAMETER?

Given `foo` in your example should be part in the equality, normally the `equals()` method should looks like

```
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!obj instanceof GenericsRunTimeType)
        return false;

    GenericsRunTimeType other = (GenericsRunTimeType) obj;

    return (this.foo.equals(obj.foo))  // !Here
    // can be better wrote as foo==obj.foo || (foo != null && foo.equals(obj.foo))
    // I wrote in a simpler form just to give you the idea

}
```

Whether the two `foo` is of the same type, it is normally the responsibility of the equals() of `foo` to deal with.  If you don't care whether the two `foo` is equals, then why should you care for whether both `foo`s are of the same type?

Of course there are other choices like what suggested by other answer, where you get the type from `foo` and compare them or pass in another `Class` object.  However I think probably not necessary in most case.